# React detect the change in iframe's src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `iframe` element inside my component and I need to somehow detect when the URL of that iframe changes. What I have tried so far:

1. Added `onLoad` callback, but this does not trigger every time I redirect in the iframe
2. Used `React.useCallback` but also does not work as I wanted to
3. Create `timeout` and get the URL from the iframe every `x` seconds

Minimalistic code example below

```
export const XComponent = (props: XComponentProps) => {
  
  const ref = React.useRef<any>();

  1.
  const onLoad = () => {
    const url = ref.current.contentWindow.location.href;
    // do stg with url
  }

  2.
  const getRef = React.useCallback((node: any) => {
    // store node into state, this was not triggered properly either
  }, []);

  3.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const url = ref.current.contentWindow.location.href;
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={ styles.albertStoremanTab }>
      <div className={ styles.container }>
        <iframe id={"iframe-my-id"} onLoad={onLoad}  src={props.defaultUrl} ref={ref}></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: same origin or cross domain? if cross domain, I believe, there is no way for parent to know what `src` frame has(because security!).

Answer (score -2):

That's simple:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // It runs only when defaultUrl changes
}, [props.defaultUrl])
```

Comment: I mean the inner URL in the iframe element, not the one from the props

Comment: `src` is `props.defaultUrl`. If the code you have is different and `src` is reading from another variable that is a  different story. Please, update the code with your case. Another suggestion, add a debugger to the onLoad function to see if it gets triggered at all.

Comment: @alireza if user click any link inside of `iframe`, then `iframe` navigates to given url despite that fact in JSX it's just `src={props.defaultUrl}`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, based on browser securities you can't do that. Any interactions user makes inside an iframe, you can't access. Unless you are the owner of the domain in the iframe.