# how can i check when react-iframe url change and get the url of after redirect?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

i was tryed with onLoad() of react-iframe package but it dont have value of contentWindow.location.ref.

my code :

```
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'
<Iframe url={exampleUrl}
        width="450px"
        height="450px"
        id="myId"
        className="myClassname"
        onLoad={e => console.log(e)} // it just have target.contentWindow without href inside this value
        display="initial"
        position="relative"/>
```

Comment: You can use the ```useRef``` hook and run subscribe to the changes of the hook value using useEffect.

Comment: Check this link out! I guess this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837708/react-detect-the-change-in-iframes-src